# Is it possible to display aggregate of multiple RSS feeds on WordPress.com?

Tags: rss, wordpress.com

I want to display content from 20 different blogs (on multiple platforms some non-WP) in a single public place such that all 20 bloggers can see and track each other's content in a single location.

Please note, I'm aware there is an rss widget to display a *single* RSS feed and I'm aware I could easily do this *self-hosted WP* with any of several plugins.

I'm solely wondering if it's possible on wp.com.  I'm assuming not, but thought it worth asking as I haven't actively used wp.com in 5+ years and don't know what's changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways of doing it, both limited by the number of articles offered by the feed:

## [Shortcode](http://en.support.wordpress.com/rss-shortcode/)

Multiple shortcodes can be combined on one page/post to aggregate multiple feeds.

```
[rss url=http://blog1.example.com/feed]
[rss url=http://blog2.example.com/feed]
<!-- etc -->
```

## [Widget](http://en.support.wordpress.com/widgets/rss-widget/)

Maximum of 20 items to display. Add as many widgets as necessary. The <kbd>Visibility</kbd> button has some nice options as well.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, had no idea this existed.  Was this recently added to .com?

Comment: I doubt it, it's quite old, at least at .org. {edit} I've updated the screenshot